# 2D games programming coordinates in C

Tags: c, 2d, coordinates, ncurses, coordinate-systems

I'm making my way through some ncurses tutorials as I want to improve some of my C programming skills. I'm at a point where the tutorial is emulating a simple tennis game.

What confuses me is this:

```
* think of posX as relating to rows, the bottom of the screen will be at
maximum Y value, so subtract 2, to set the racket near the bottom */
p.posX = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 2;

/* think of posY as relating to a column, the middle of the screen will be
at the middle of the screen_width, divided by 2, to set racket at center */
p.posY = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
```

and say, the racket is moved left by the user:

```
void moveRacketLeft() {
if (p.posY - 2 > 0) { // ensure racket is still on screen
    mvprintw(p.posX, p.posY-1, "   ");  // if true, it will print an empty space, deleting the racket
    p.posY --;    // remember to decrement, as we are going to the left
    }
```

}

What confuses me about this, is that the X and Y positions have seem to be reversed and I don't know how to logically 'get it'.

Is there some kind of grey area between conventional coordinates in C programming and the use of the ncurses library? Or is the tutorial making a mistake?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` and `y` coordinates in curses are as you expect: `x` is the horizontal coordinate, corresponding to columns. `y` is the vertical coordinate, cooresponding to rows.

But in curses, these coordinates are usually given in the order `y`, `x`. For example, the prototype to `mfprintw` mentioned in your code snippet is:

```
int mvprintw(int y, int x, const char *fmt, ...);
```

And there are even functions (or macros. rather) that have `yx` in their name, e.g. `getyx`.

I imagine that this notation was chosen, because it reflects the way that two-dimensional arrays are addressed in C: `array[row][col]`.